# Bootstrap 3 carousel not load/displaying properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm converting some psd files using html5boilerplate and Twitter Bootstrap. Now mine problem is pretty simple.

I want to divide container in half so I can load a carousel on one side and some text on the other, I know how to divide it but when I load carousel I got only this [image: simply it is not loading like it should be.]. Now I know and I've seen on SO that it is about jQuery not loading properly, but everything is loading I just can see where is the error.

Can some one please check mine index.html, and explain me what is wrong whit this picture.
Thank you.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang=""> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fotn-awesome.min.css">
        <style>
            body {
                padding-top: 50px;
                padding-bottom: 20px;
            }
        </style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="#" height=30 width=41></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul id="navbar" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Apartments</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li style="padding-top: 8px;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info round">GET STARTED</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <h1>Hello, NYC!</h1>
        <p>Place to put NYC Bay picture!</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <!-- JOIN SOCIETE section -->
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
               &nbsp;
               &nbsp;
               <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span>&nbsp;JOIN SOCIETE</h2>
              <p>Literati Group Hosing LLC provides furnished housing for the</p>
                  <p>New York City international community of students, interns,</p>
                  <p>and young professionals.</p>
           </div> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <!-- container devider -->
          <p style="padding: 30px;"></p> 
       </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <!-- SOCIETE row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-2">
            <h4><strong>No Broker or Hidden Fees</strong></h4>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h4><strong>Extremely Fast.</strong></h4>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
       </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h4><strong>Flexible Lease Terms</strong></h4>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-2">
            <h4><strong>Operations and Engeneering.</strong></h4>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h4><strong>Networking.</strong></h4>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
       </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h4><strong>Safety.</strong></h4>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <!-- container devider -->
          <p style="padding: 30px;"></p> 
       </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
           <!--Carousel Best Appartments Section--> 
              <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide col-sm-6" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                  <div class="item active">
                    <img src="..." alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      ...
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="..." alt="...">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      ...
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  ...
                </div>

                <!-- Controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
              </div>
       </div><!-- end row --> 
    </div><!-- end carousel container -->
<hr />
      <footer>
        <p>&copy; Company 2015</p>
      </footer>
    </div> <!-- /container -->        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

        <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
        <script>
            (function(b,o,i,l,e,r){b.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l;b[l]||(b[l]=
            function(){(b[l].q=b[l].q||[]).push(arguments)});b[l].l=+new Date;
            e=o.createElement(i);r=o.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];
            e.src='//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
            r.parentNode.insertBefore(e,r)}(window,document,'script','ga'));
            ga('create','UA-XXXXX-X','auto');ga('send','pageview');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding http to jquery on your script tag.

Comment: The slider is working for me, by removing your script tags and re adding them in http://codepen.io/jfoutch/pen/dYEpEJ   sorry, just re-read the post.. The slider was working but the layout is wrong

Comment: for some reason I'm seeing the same error in your codepen, the carousel is not loaded as I see it, using Firefox

Comment: The slider is functioning but has no images to show

Comment: Yes, you are right, hate when this happens, need to sleep, thank you